# Como fazer um laço de repetição aguardar uma função ser executada,para prosseguir o loop

Tags: node.js

Tenho um programa que faz o download do arquivo que é passado para ele, segue o código

```
function Download(arquivo) {
  download("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/ptwiki/20190801/" + arquivo).then(
    data => {
      fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/downloads/" + arquivo, data);
      console.log("Download concluido, arquivo " + arquivo);
    }
  );
}
```

tenho uma outra lista que tem todos os arquivos que deve ser baixado através dessa função ,ela está contida dentro de um array . Se eu fizer

```
Download(lista[posicaoDoArquivoQueQueroBaixar]) ;
```

Ele faz o Download corretamente,agora se eu fizer um for, ou forEach pra baixar automaticamente, ele dar um erro por que chama varios Downloads ao mesmo tempo,

```
lista.forEach(arquivo =>{
  Download(arquivo);
 });
```

O erro que apresenta é esse

```
(node:15351) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: HTTPError: Response code 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)
    at EventEmitter.ee.on.res (/home/raellopes/Área de Trabalho/Trabalho/split xml document/node_modules/got/index.js:482:24)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at getResponse (/home/raellopes/Área de Trabalho/Trabalho/split xml document/node_modules/got/index.js:320:5)
    at Immediate.setImmediate (/home/raellopes/Área de Trabalho/Trabalho/split xml document/node_modules/got/index.js:147:6)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
(node:15351) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15351) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Tem alguma forma de eu usar o for ou forEach mas que o próximo loop só executasse após o Download ser concluído?

(Observação , a lista tem mais de 60 arquivos,pra ser exato 67, testei executando um por vez Download(lista[x]) onde X é a posição de 0 a 67 e o download é feito corretamente,o erro só dar caso eu chamar mais de 3x o Download ao mesmo tempo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode realizar esse processamento utilizando async/await do javascript.

Primeiro você ajustará a função que realiza o download para retornar uma 
Promise, dessa forma você poderá utilizar o método await para aguardar que a função finalize para proceder para o próximo item. Veja:

```js
async function Download(arquivo) {
  const data = await download("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/ptwiki/20190801/" + arquivo)
  await fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/downloads/" + arquivo, data);
  return arquivo;
}
```

Agora você precisará utilizar um escopo async para que seja possível executar
um de cada vez.

```js
(async () => {
  for(const arquivo of lista){
    await Download(arquivo);
  }
})()
```

Isso fará com que um download seja executado após o outro.

Comment: Estou com duvida novamente,voce pode me chamar no whats pra me dar uma força? (98)98307-9191